# InfluxdDB query - select field from multiple measuremnts

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I'm trying to get an exact field from multiple measurements with the same naming pattern.

Let's say the measurements are like:

```
some.stats.123
some.stats.456
some.stats.789
```

I'm trying to get `test` value, this is possible with:

```
select test from "some.stats.123";
```

and I would like to call it like:

```
select test from "some.stats.*";
```

The above query is accepted by influx but returns nothing. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out regex can be used here instead of wildcard:

```
select test from /some.stats.*/
```

works like charm :)